# Stuck at 98.7% complete in Stranger Things. What am I missing?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I have completed every level and every quest (that I know of) in the game, but I am only at 98.7% complete.

I have found all 8 Eggos, all 8 VHS tapes, all 12 garden gnomes, and all 40 heart pieces. I've unlocked Eleven and watched the movie in the Hawk Theater.

In my inventory, I have 3 backpacks, an aluminum bat, a D-cell flashlight, a Canadian tuxedo, a 20-sided die, a spiked club, and a Ghostbusters lunchbox. I also have the hazmat suit, dynamite, flowers, and the key, but those are all required to complete the game anyway. There are no quest items remaining and I've talked to everyone in the game.

What am I missing?

I'm playing on hard if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you're missing max's mask and eleven's maple syrup? the mask is in the newly unlocked house to the right of the school and the maple syrup can be found by going back to the middle school gym with eleven and jumping into the sensory deprivation bath which will lead you to a room with the maple syrup in it!

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks! Didn't notice the new house open up and forgot about the pool in the gym.

Answer (score 0):

Buy doughnut and give to Powell’s infront the Lab(Chapter1)